# Order converting to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this order by clause in my stored procedure

```
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN @sortDir = 2 THEN
      CASE
            WHEN @sortCol = 'ProductNumber' THEN ProductId
            WHEN @sortCol = 'ProductName' THEN CAST(V.[Name] AS NVARCHAR)
            ...
      END
 END DESC
```

I wanted to sort via the column given the @sortCol

It's giving me this error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Product 28' to
> data type int.

Why?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Related - do NOT get into the lazy and bad habit of casting to (or declaring) a variable-length datatype without specifying a length.

Comment: Note that this kind of "dynamic ordering" means indexes cannot be used and an explicit sort is required in the query plan. If you would like to hit indexes, switch to separate queries with an `if`, or dynamic SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that `case` is an expression that returns a single type.  And ints beat out strings.

Instead of worrying about types, use separate expressions:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @sortDir = 2 AND @sortCol = 'ProductNumber' THEN ProductId END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @sortDir = 2 AND @sortCol = 'ProductName' THEN v.Name END) DESC,
         . . .
```

This is a bit more verbose, but it avoids all type conversions.